# maven release plugin hanging

Tags: maven, cvs, maven-release-plugin, maven-scm-plugin

I'm trying to release a CVS project with the mvn release plugin.

I've succeeded with mvn release:prepare but when I run release:perform it hangs due to what seems to be a leading slash on the CVS module

/cust/shared_code

```
[INFO] [release:perform {execution: default-cli}]
[INFO] Checking out the project to perform the release ...
[INFO] Executing: /bin/sh -c cd /home/jmorgan/cvs_src/HEAD/cust-repo/cust/shared_code/target && cvs -z3 -f -d :pserver:jmorgan@pserver:/cvsroot-cust -q checkout -r cust-shared_code-8_0_4 -d checkout /cust/shared_code
[INFO] Working directory: /home/jmorgan/cvs_src/HEAD/cust-repo/cust/shared_code/target
```

This hangs...

Removing the slash

```
/bin/sh -c cd /home/jmorgan/cvs_src/HEAD/cust-repo/cust/shared_code/target && cvs -z3 -f -d :pserver:jmorgan@pserver:/cvsroot-cust -q checkout -r cust-shared_code-8_0_4 -d checkout cust/shared_code
U checkout/acct-dcash-xml
U checkout/acct-dcash
U checkout/acct_qry
U checkout/acct_totals
...
```

This starts checking out as i'd expect

My maven-scm-plugin v1.8.1 settings are

```
<scm>
<connection>scm:cvs:pserver:${env.USER}:${password}@pserver:/cvsroot-cust:cust/shared_code</connection>
<developerConnection>scm:cvs:pserver:${env.USER}:${password}@pserver:/cvsroot-cust:cust/shared_code</developerConnection>
</scm>

 <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-scm-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <providerImplementations>
                    <cvs>cvs_native</cvs>
                </providerImplementations>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

It looks like its related to http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/SCM-216 though this was apparently fixed in 1.0-beta-4

Any help would be most appreciated

James

---- UPDATE

It seems my release.properties is incorrect

```
#release configuration
#Fri Feb 15 14:58:18 GMT 2013
project.dev.com.cust.shared\:cust-shared_code=8.0.5-SNAPSHOT
scm.tag=cust-shared_code-8_0_4
scm.url=scm\:cvs\:pserver\:jmorgan\:${password}@pserver\:/cvsroot-cust\:/cust/shared_code
preparationGoals=clean verify
project.rel.com.cust.shared\:cust-shared_code=8.0.4
scm.commentPrefix=[maven-release-plugin]
project.scm.com.cust.shared\:cust-shared_code.tag=HEAD
project.scm.com.cust.shared\:cust-shared_code.developerConnection=scm\:cvs\:pserver\:builder\:${password}@pserver\:/cvsroot-cust\:/cust/shared_code
project.scm.com.cust.shared\:cust-shared_code.connection=scm\:cvs\:pserver\:builder\:${password}@pserver\:/cvsroot-cust\:cust/shared_code
exec.additionalArguments=-P artifactory
completedPhase=end-release
```

Though unsure how to correct this

Comment: what version of maven-scm-provider-cvs is in you local repository? The version they fixed the issue does not seem to be in maven central so you may use a broken version

Comment: Hi, thanks for getting back to me. I have v1.8 ./org/apache/maven/scm/maven-scm-providers-cvs/1.8/maven-scm-providers-cvs-1.8.pom

Comment: I think I may be getting somewhere. Ive changed the maven-release-plugin version to 2.4 and when calling release:prepare/perform I use mvn release:prepare -Dmaven.scm.provider.cvs.implementation=cvs_native. It now allows me to perform, though it only seems to be releasing a snapshot to artifactory. Im going to have a play and see whats going on. Thanks very much for your time.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this issue as I mentioned in my last comment by updating to the latest version of all the plugins. maven-release-plugin v2.4 and maven-scm-provider-cvs v1.8